# Give out IDs which are present in the list and not present in table

Tags: mysql

i have a list of ID's like (1,2,3,4,5,6). I want to find out how many of these id's in list does not exists in the table. how do i do this ?

```
-- table --
id    name
1     a
2     b
3     c   
4     d  
5     e 
6     f
7     g
```

List of Id's which i get is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13

so when query i should get out result like 8,9,10,11,12,13 which are not in the table

Comment: which table are you talking about?

Comment: how do you want to compare the list and the table containing the id's? are these two columns in the same table?

Comment: Do you just need to know how many, or do you need to know which ones are missing?

Comment: @SashiKant Kant  - Mysql Table.

Comment: @kevinm   - Its 1 column in table.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  6-c
FROM (
  SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) as c 
  FROM 
    my_table 
  WHERE 
    ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
) as tmp
```

And to find out which ones are missing :

```
SELECT
    zID
FROM (
    SELECT 1 as zID UNION
    SELECT 2 as zID UNION
    SELECT 3 as zID UNION
    SELECT 4 as zID UNION
    SELECT 5 as zID UNION
    SELECT 6 as zID UNION
    SELECT 7 as zID UNION
    SELECT 8 as zID UNION
    SELECT 9 as zID UNION
    SELECT 10 as zID UNION
    SELECT 11 as zID UNION
    SELECT 12 as zID UNION
    SELECT 13 as zID UNION
    SELECT 14 as zID UNION
    SELECT 15 as zID UNION
) as t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT(ID) as mID 
    FROM 
        my_table 
) as t2
    ON t1.zID = t2.mID
WHERE
    t2.mID IS NULL
```

Comment: @Stephan - i want list of Id's

Comment: @Hacker i've added the query for that

Comment: @Stephan - but i get list of 100-200 ID's

Comment: @Hacker i just saw the updated question and i've updated the query again

Answer (score 3):

This will return the list of IDs in the list that aren't in the table.

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM (SELECT 1 id
      UNION
      SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6) t1
LEFT JOIN MyTable t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

If you do things like this often, you might want to create a permanent table containing constants, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (id int primary key);
INSERT INTO numbers (id) VALUES (0), (1), (2), ..., (1000);
```

Then you can do:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM numbers
JOIN MyTable t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
AND t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: @Barmar - but i get list of 100-200 ID's

Comment: @Hacker See my second version

Comment: +1 I was trying about the same. [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4082/1)